# How can I dump an entire object and it's values?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, object

I have an object called user.

```
$user = $data['user'];
```

I can access it's properties directly by doing `$user->first_name` and I will get the value. However, I need to see everything within the object since I want to cherry pick data.

I've tried a few different methods, but nothing is giving me what I need. I've tried a `foreach`, `get_object_vars` and I'm still not getting everything.

Here is a dump of what I'm seeing when using `var_dump($user)`:

```
        object(WP_User)#3017 (8) {
      ["data"]=>
      object(stdClass)#2997 (10) {
        ["ID"]=>
        string(3) "215"
        ["user_login"]=>
        string(20) "test@gmail.com"
        ["user_pass"]=>
        string(34) "$P$fdsa4r3wafs43"
        ["user_nicename"]=>
        string(19) "test-com"
        ["user_email"]=>
        string(20) "test@gmail.com"
        ["user_url"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["user_registered"]=>
        string(19) "2019-03-21 00:58:47"
        ["user_activation_key"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["user_status"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["display_name"]=>
        string(26) "Full display"
      }
      ["ID"]=>
      int(215)
      ["caps"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["um_instructor"]=>
        bool(true)
      }
      ["cap_key"]=>
      string(15) "wp_capabilities"
      ["roles"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(13) "um_instructor"
      }
      ["allcaps"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["read"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["um_instructor"]=>
        bool(true)
      }
      ["filter"]=>
      NULL
      ["site_id":"WP_User":private]=>
      int(1)
    }
```

Any and all help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump();`?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, I did without any luck. Still only getting part of the results.

Comment: var_dump() is for debugging, it's supposed to show everything. can you give us some example that it shows part of an object?

Comment: Sure thing. I just posted it. I'm still learning PHP, so I appreciate the patience/help

Comment: You mean, you only want to see all the fields of an object without writing statements to fetch a single field one after one. Mean to say, you want to see something like `{"username": "Lz430", "first_name": "Lz", "last_name": "FourThirty", "age": 20}` using a single statement.

Comment: I dont get it,you said var_dump doesn't work and you showed the results which clearly means that is working.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. On the very same page I have stuff like `$user->ID` or `$user->profile_previous_experience` and I have data there. But that's not showing up in the `var_dump`. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: maybe you are looking for an output like the one from the kint-debugger. https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/kint-debugger/   install and activate the plugin and afterwards you can print all info about an object/array with d($obj);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `$user->profile_previous_experience` field in the output of `var_dump`, because this value is returned by "magic method" [`__get()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User#get.28_.24key_.29) of `WP_User` class.

I assume that `profile_previous_experience` is a User's customfield. You can use [`get_user_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) function to get value of a customfield:

```
$user_experience = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'profile_previous_experience');
```

You can also fetch [all the customfields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta#Getting_all_meta_data) with the same function (by omitting second parameter):

```
$user_cfs = get_user_meta($user->ID);
```

If you're not familiar with "magic methods" in PHP, take a look at [properties overloading examples](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) in the official PHP docs

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. It looks like my field isn't being captured by the front-end form. I'll have to investigate further. But this dumped everything on the user object. Thanks!